# Recursive Pointer to Element function gives Segmentation Fault (11)

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion, segmentation-fault

My little Program is build this way:

- I have an Object `Element` that is defined as following:

  ```
  struct element {
      element* next;
  } typedef element;
  ```
- My Program is calling this recursive function...

  ```
  int dosomething(element* a) {
      if (a != NULL)
          return dosomething(a->next);
      else
      return 0;
  }
  ```
- In the main function:

  ```
  int main(void) {
      element* a = (element *) malloc(sizeof(element));
      a-> next = (element *) malloc(sizeof(element));

      cout << dosomething(a) << endl;

      return 0;
  }
  ```

When running this Program, I get:

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

So, `a` and `a->next` is defined. `a->next->next` should be `NULL`, so the function should just return `0`?

Why isn't this working?

Comment: Don't use `malloc` in C++.

Comment: "a->next->next should be NULL" - why?

Comment: `malloc` does not intialise the memory in any way. So `a->next->next` cannot be assumed to be `NULL`.

Comment: Please do not tag questions as both C++ and C; only tag the language you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a->next->next` is not NULL. ```malloc`` does not gurantee that the allocated memory region will be initialized to something (i.e. it has the value of what has previously been there).

Also, [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

```
int main(void) {
    element* a = (element *) malloc(sizeof(element));
    a-> next = (element *) malloc(sizeof(element));
    a->next->next = NULL;

    cout << dosomething(a) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to initialize the next-pointer with 0, otherwise it is uninitialized and "a != NULL" will not be true under some circumstances. You could use calloc instead of malloc, which initializes the memory with 0

Answer (score 0):

You weren't making the last element `NULL` - `malloc` doesn't do this for you. You should use C++ constructs, too. They're very helpful.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Element {
  Element* next;
};

int do_something(Element* a) {
  if(a) {
    do_something(a->next);
  }
  return 0;
}

int main() {
  Element* last = NULL;
  Element* next = new Element;
  next->next = last;
  Element* first = new Element;
  first->next = next;
  std::cout << do_something(first) << std::endl;
  delete first;
  delete next;
  delete last;
  return 0;
}
```

[ideone](https://ideone.com/E7zCOG)